# Is this aphorism about gentiles as problematic as it seems?

Tags: gentiles, sexuality, bein-adam-lachavero

I often hear among younger, apparently fromm men the aphorism "[gentile women]<sup>1</sup> are for [sexual] practice". This has always struck me as bizarre, due to the importance of the reproductive act for its explicit purpose. Does anyone actually weigh in as to whether this is as problematic as it seems?

<sup>1</sup> The actual quote I've heard uses a derogatory term here.

Comment: Its a stupid saying ,which is completely assur as you are well aware

Comment: Not all who appear/claim to be frum (or "fromm") actually are.....

Comment: @sam, I am well aware of this, in fact, I once had a wonderful hashkafic debate where I disproved this expression, however, I wondered what the actual halachot on the matter were.

Comment: Is your question "Is sex with a gentile prohibited?" or "How prohibited is sex with a gentile?" or something else?

Comment: Effectively, I'm asking about the halachic/hashkafic stance regarding both whether sex with non-Jews is prohibited and the laissez-faire attitude associated with this.

Comment: I had to see the earlier revisions of the question to understand it. As it stands now, the word "[sexual] practice", especially coming after a bracketed-out bowdlerization, looks like a bowdlerization (which it's not), and "practice" looks (to me at least) like it means "activity". The question's closed now, but if it's to be reopened I recommend clarification.

Comment: I find it odd that you "often hear" this, considering that I've never heard this. If you really hear this often, I suggest that you stop associating with slimy reprobates in the future regardless of whether they masquerade as religious.

Comment: I hear it often enough that I think to ask it, though not often enough to think that they are actually so-much slimy as they are making a **very** bad joke

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51153/5323

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Rambam in Hilchos Issurei Biah 12:6 holds there is an issue kares,see the chapter in detail. See also the Shulchan Aruch Even Haezer 16 with the meforshim who hold its not only a Rabbinic prohibition but rather a Torah prohibition.

The saying is just an immature attitude of relationships on a whole and is entirely prohibited.