# Relations between non-Jewish men and Jewish woman

Tags: halacha

I remember learning this halacha in the Steinselz Talmud. I believe it was in Sotah. It covered the prohibition of Jewish men with non-Jewish women, but there was no prohibition between non-Jewish men and Jewish women. My intuition and I believe most poskim would say that this is prohibited. But can somebody confirm or deny this hypothesis for me by bringing down a source.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51153/759

Comment: You mean esther and achashverosh

Answer (score 0):

Deuteronomy 7:3

You shall not intermarry with them; **you shall not give your daughter to his son**, and you shall not take his daughter for your son.

Comment: Arguably this only applies to marriage per se.

Comment: Right, how about relations?